# Regular expression to match a white space character before the actual pattern - PHP

Tags: php, regex

I have this string -:
`@Harry @Harry are great twins with @Harry`

I would want to match `@Harry` in the above string. But on one condition -:

> @Harry should be preceeded by either nothing or a white space
>   character only, same goes for succession too.

So here 3 matches must be found. Currently i am doing this, but in vain -:
`(\s|^$)\@Harry(\s|^$)`.

Comment: Could you also add an example of what `@Harry`s you would not want matched? Also, you should remove the `$` from the starting group and the `^` from the final group.

Comment: Can you provide what output you want from this input string.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`^$` means an empty string.
[`\s` means more than a whitespace ([source](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)) so you should just use a whitespace :)] <= Unnecessary

So, without taking the whitespace as part of the match:

```
"/(?<=^|\s)@Harry(?=\s|$)/"
```

**Edit:**
[Source](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) for the lookarounds.
Also, if you want to match the whitespaces, remove those lookarounds.

Comment: The OP wants a white space character, not necessarily a whitespace. Also, the lookbehind is unnecessary.

Comment: @Asad "*@Harry should be preceeded by either nothing or a white space character only, same goes for succession too.*" The lookbehind goes for the preceded part. As for the whitespace character, I misread, but I guess he changed that if it was not what he wanted. Editing though.

Comment: @Loamhoof Perhaps I misunderstood the OP then, I thought he wanted the space to be in the match. You've covered that in your answer though, so +1

Comment: @Asad it's not clear, he simply said he wanted the string to be preceded and followed by a whitespace character. I just assumed he didn't want it part of the match, but still specified how to change it so it is.